# Windows 7 Cisco VPN client hash verification failed

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I am having a problem with connecting to a Cisco VPN in Windows 7. According to the below error log I am getting problem is with the group password. But the same password works correctly on my Windows XP PC.

```
1      12:26:14.387  03/18/12  Sev=Warning/3    IKE/0xE3000057
The received HASH payload cannot be verified

2      12:26:14.387  03/18/12  Sev=Warning/2    IKE/0xE300007E
Hash verification failed... may be configured with invalid group password.

3      12:26:14.387  03/18/12  Sev=Warning/2    IKE/0xE300009B
Failed to authenticate peer (Navigator:904)
```

I am using Cisco VPN Client 5.0.10.0600 and Windows 7 professional with Service Pack 1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with Cisco, but I *NEVER* got the Cisco VPN client working reliably on any OS other than WinXP, and switched to the ShrewSoft (www.shrew.net) VPN client.

Comment: @EKW Cisco VPN has worked fine for me on XP x86, and Vista/7 x86/x64.  Most problems that aren't cleared up by a user password reset are usually fixed by a re-install.  Our client installations have the connection profiles pre-configured, though.

Comment: @Indika Have you tried copying the *.pcf files from the Profiles sub-folder of the VPN Client's Program Files folder?

Comment: @Iszi That solved my problem. Now I can connect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's problems with your connection configurations, and you have another working system, you should try copying the connection profiles from that working system.

The profiles can usually be found in the VPN Client's Program Files folder.  This should be one of:

- `C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\`

From there, look for a folder called `profiles`.  In that folder should be one or more files with extensions ending in `.pcf`.  Copy these files from the working computer, to the same location on your malfunctioning system.  Re-start the VPN client and see if it will work from there.

If this fails, re-installing the VPN client may be helpful.